# Using Ajax to display the values of an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I'm building a project that uses a function called `Chat.fetch()`; it's an asynchronous function that pulls an array of strings from the server. It's an ajax function that for purposes of the project is already defined, I just have to call it correctly. There is another function we are given called Chat.display() which takes a string and displays it in bulleted form on the console. Right now this is what I've got:
I'm getting an error that says cannot read property length of undefined. So I guess.length is undefined for superArray?  The goal is to create this function and use it as the call back function for Chat.fetch(). Do you guys have any idea why I'm getting this .length error? I'm pretty confused. Thanks!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>


    Chat.guide.start();


    <h2>Borken Chat</h2>

    <input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send" disabled>send</button>



    <ul class="messages">

      <script>
    var list;
    var superArray=[];
    darray=function(superArray){
      var y=superArray.length;
      for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        Chat.display(x[i]);
      }
    }
    Chat.fetch(darray(list));
  </script>

    </ul>

  </body>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Typically the values are just returned in the response text of the XMLHttpRequest object...

Comment: We need to know more about `.fetch`, or about the app in general.  If `.fetch` returns a promise (an object, which might have a `.done` function or a `.then` function, or something similar) then you can chain it (`Chat.fetch().done(chatbox.update_messages);` if not, then figure out if there's a place in `Chat` where you can register a function to be called when `.fetch` comes back.  It would also help if you just dumped the contents of the `.fetch` function.  Your program keeps running code until `.fetch` comes back from the server... then the results are put in a callback, or saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple page that uses Ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function loadXMLDoc()
   {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","<<URL>>",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Results will go here</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get Results</button>

</body>
</html>
```

See where the xmlHttp.responseText is used? That's where you'll get your strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any clue what code you have, but the basic idea is something like this (using jQuery, don't know if that is in your stack or not).  And this assumes Chat.fetch() is synchronous, otherwise you'll need to trigger an event when it's done or use a promise or something.

```
messages = Chat.fetch();
for (i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
      $('#chat-window').append( '<br>' + messages[i] );
}
```

Comment: `.fetch` is practically guaranteed to be async, given the description, unless the chat-app is doing it wrong.